# Should this could not break out of the inner loop?

Tags: vb.net

i need to break out of an inner loop and i've been advised that exit loop is not the best way to do so. So i've thought of another way to do so, i want to get the value within the if statement, but it doesnt appear to be working properly.

```
 While Bavailable = True

            For Each position In MyPosList

                If creditPoints = "20" And semester = "1" And year = "Year 1" Then
                    Blongthin = False
                    BlongFat = False
                    If position.strLabel = "a1" And available(0) = "True" Then

                        pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                        count += 1
                        available(0) = blnavailable
                        Bavailable = False
                        MsgBox(Bavailable)

                    ElseIf position.strLabel = "b1" And available(1) <> "False" Then
                        pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                        'position.blnAvail = False
                        count += 1
                        available(1) = blnavailable
                        Bavailable = False

                    ElseIf position.strLabel = "c1" And available(2) <> "False" Then
                        pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                        position.blnAvail = False
                        count += 1
                        available(2) = blnavailable
                        Bavailable = False
                    End If
```

You see that i'm using Bavailable to try and break out of the loop to get the value pos in the instance of one of these if's conditions are returned true? any help?

Comment: Hungarian type notation?

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the premise.  If the entire reason you using that outer while loop is to avoid using `Exit For` then you should get rid of the `While`.  If your conditions inside the For are really, really long and you want to avoid jumping out in more than on sport then do this:

```
For Each position In MyPosList 

   Dim breakEarly As Boolean = False

   If someCondition Then

      'logic, logic, logic
      'logic, logic, logic
      'logic, logic, logic
      breakEarly = True

   ElseIf someOtherCondition Then

      'logic, logic, logic
      'logic, logic, logic
      'logic, logic, logic
      breakEarly = True

   ElseIf etc, 
   ElseIf etc, 
   ElseIf etc, 
   End If

   If breakEarly Then

      'do any common pre-exit code here

      'now bail
      Exit For

   End If

Next
```

Comment: I disagree. If you want to process only a part of a collection use While. If you want to process the whole collection use for.

Comment: @somos Ack, commented to the wrong post, stupid phone.  See my notes above.  Additionally, foreach yields easier to read code for many situations when using an index variable is not wise.  For example, a foreach drastically outperforms index based iterating on a linked list

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using For loops when you don't want to loop all the items. In this situation I prefer using a While. How about something like:

```
Dim index As Integer
index = 0

While Not Found And index < MyPosList.Count
    ' Do whatever and update Found when required
    index = index + 1
While End
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    While Bavailable
        For Each position In MyPosList
            If Bavailable Then  'Add loop controls to inner loop
                If creditPoints = "20" And semester = "1" And Year() = "Year 1" Then
                    Blongthin = False
                    BlongFat = False
                    If position.strLabel = "a1" And available(0) = "True" Then
                        pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                        count += 1
                        available(0) = blnavailable
                        Bavailable = False
                        MsgBox(Bavailable)

                    ElseIf position.strLabel = "b1" And available(1) <> "False" Then
                        pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                        'position.blnAvail = False
                        count += 1
                        available(1) = blnavailable
                        Bavailable = False

                    ElseIf position.strLabel = "c1" And available(2) <> "False" Then
                        pos = position.strX & " " & position.strY
                        position.blnAvail = False
                        count += 1
                        available(2) = blnavailable
                        Bavailable = False
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next position
    End While
```

although I am extremely interested in what exactly is wrong about `Exit For` and `Exit While`...

Comment: The break the concept of structured programming. What't the difference between an Exit, an Exit While and a Goto statement?

Comment: I agree that `Goto` is bad, which is why I stopped using it (entirely) in 1984. However, there is a considerable difference between an `Exit` statement and a `Goto` statement. An `Exit` statement (For, While, etc.) exits the loop in a clean fashion and program control resumes on the next statement following the loop. A `Goto` statement can jump you to any arbitrary line in your code base. `Exit` statements do **not** break the concept of structured programming. They are, in fact, intentionally in the language to help **maintain** the concept of structured programming.

Comment: IMHO opinion a method should have one entry point and one exit point. Other shortcuts mask the real logic of the method and breaks its structure.

Comment: `Exit Function`, `Exit Sub`,  and `Exit Property` give you alternate means of exiting a method. I agree that these are bad practice, but `Exit Do`, `Exit For`, `Exit Select`, `Exit Try`, and `Exit While` do not exit a method and flow control resumes immediately on the next statement. I have no qualms about using these. There are other opinions regarding `break` and similar statements if you care to peruse them (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216359/break-statements-in-the-real-world)

Answer (score 0):

If `Exit For` or `Exit While` make your code more readable, use them!
No sense adding a variable whose only purpose adds unneeded complexity.

If you could move most of the internal logic into separate functions, even better.

Comment: Completely disagree. Read my comment at pete answer. I mean, do whatever makes your code more readable, of course. But a statement that breaks the execution flow never makes your code more readable.

Comment: return statements do the same thing...break the flow of execution( Unless you limit yourself to, maximum, one return per function as the last line).

Comment: This is something I always do. My methods always have one entry point and one exit point. That's an structured program IMHO.

Comment: @somos There is nothing wrong with using an iterator (for each) to enumerate a list and likewise it is common to need to break out of such a loop.  Given a foreach, using exit for is the only way

Comment: Note that I too only have one spot that exits/breaks out of the for loop.  Same style as a single return statement